# AutoMapper, use mapping on profile

Tags: c#, automapper

I am creating a AutoMapper configuration, where the structure dose not match the desination in 1:1, i have to wrap my primary and secondary contact in ContactResponse object. I can not figure out how to use the mapping i created before to map the Contact object to a CommunicationContactResponse without redoing the config

```
public class VendorResponseMappingProfile : Profile {

    public VendorResponseMappingProfile()
    {
        this.CreateMap<Contact, CommunicationContactResponse>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Phone, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Phone))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Email, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Email));

        this.CreateMap<Vendor, VendorResponse>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Memo, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Memo))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Active, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Active))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Contact, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new ContactResponse
            {
                // Here i have to redo the mapping from above are there a way to use the mapping from above instead?
                PrimaryContact = src.PrimaryContact != null ? new CommunicationContactResponse
                {
                    Phone = src.PrimaryContact.Phone,
                    Email = src.PrimaryContact.Email
                } : null,
                SecondaryContact = src.SecondaryContact != null ? new CommunicationContactResponse
                {
                    Phone = src.SecondaryContact.Phone,
                    Email = src.SecondaryContact.Email
                } : null
            }));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the [Custom Value Resolver](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html) to use the mapping rule that has been registered for both `PrimaryContact` and `SecondaryContact` fields mapping from `Contact` to `CommunicationContactResponse`.

While AutoMapper will automatically map the source and destination members if both have the same naming. Thus you don't need to specify the mapping rule for each member [unless](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Projection.html):

> Without extra configuration, AutoMapper requires a flattened destination to match the source type’s naming structure. When you want to project source values into a destination that does not exactly match the source structure, you must specify custom member mapping definitions.

**Solution 1:**

```cs
public class VendorResponseMappingProfile : Profile 
{

    public VendorResponseMappingProfile()
    {
        this.CreateMap<Contact, CommunicationContactResponse>();

        this.CreateMap<Vendor, VendorResponse>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Contact, opt => opt.MapFrom((src, dest, srcMember, context) => new ContactResponse
            {
                PrimaryContact = context.Mapper.Map<CommunicationContactResponse>(src.PrimaryContact),
                SecondaryContact = context.Mapper.Map<CommunicationContactResponse>(src.SecondaryContact)
            }));
    }
}
```

---

**(Updated) Solution 2:**

As suggested by @Lucian, a mapping from `Vendor` to `ContactResponse` is another option that is more simple.

```cs
public class VendorResponseMappingProfile : Profile 
{

    public VendorResponseMappingProfile()
    {
        this.CreateMap<Contact, CommunicationContactResponse>();

        this.CreateMap<Vendor, VendorResponse>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Contact, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));

        this.CreateMap<Vendor, ContactResponse>();
    }
}
```

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/P2UC5u)

Comment: A map from `Vendor` to `ContactResponse` would simplify things.

Comment: Thanks, @LucianBargaoanu for the precious feedback. Had updated the answer accordingly. =D

Comment: Thank you very much. This is great information, especially the fact that i can get the context and use mapping for that solves all the problems i have had with the AutoMapper.